# How to create init methods for UIViews in storyboard?

Tags: ios, properties, subclassing

I have a class `PLButton` with two properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *purpleColor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *grayColor;
```

and its initializer:

```
- (instancetype)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    self.purpleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:142.0/255.0 green:23.0/255.0 blue:126.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.grayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:239.0/255.0 green:239.0/255.0 blue:239.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
return self;
```

}

Also I have a `PLEventButton` as a subclass of `PLButton`:

and initializer inside:

```
- (instancetype)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    return self;
}
return self;
```

}

Those classes I assign in storyboard to UIButtons. 
Why those properties are not working at all in both: PLButton and PLEventButton (they are nil)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object in storyboard are init by the initWithCoder method.
So just call  your initialization method within.

```
 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder 
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        [self myInitialization];
    }

    return self;
}
```